# Exception in RegEx pattern

Tags: java, regex, json

I'm want to parse JSON like:

```
{"response":[9816,{"vid":166941761,"owner_id":-460389,"title":"Хочу         спиться!","description":"Вкусная группа БОРЩ - http:\/\/vk.com\/borsch<br\/><br\/>","duration":45,"link":"video-460389_166941761","image":"http:\/\/cs322230.vk.me\/u56348533\/video\/m_ddba3f2b.jpg","image_medium":"http:\/\/cs322230.vk.me\/u56348533\/video\/l_809f4d95.jpg","date":1385374022,"views":20981,"comments":135,"player":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/4Ik-rjxf3dw"},{"vid":166474172,"owner_id":-460389,"title":"Скороговорка от Джигурды для Борща","description":"Вкусная гру..
```

And i need to delete first element that respresend total videos count. I'm using

```
json = json.replaceAll(".*[0-9],{", "");
json = "{\"response\":[" + json;
```

adn getting:

```
 12-03 08:49:10.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2445): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:         Error in {min,max} interval near index 9:
 12-03 08:49:10.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2445): .*[0-9],{
```

Comment: I'm all for quick regex fixes, but you really should be using a json parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Nikos said: escape the `{`

But it looks like you current method leaves you with invalid json. You're removing the `{` but the closing `}` is still going to be there, so you need to add that `{` back in as part of the replacement:

```
json = json.replaceAll(".*[0-9],{", "{\"response\":[{");
                                                    ^
```

For your example data though, you could just be using

```
json = json.replaceAll("\\[[0-9]+", "[");
```

Comment: Thanks now it's working. Final result: json = json.replaceAll("\\[[0-9]+,", "[");

Answer (score 1):

Escape the last `{`, i.e.:

```
json = json.replaceAll(".*[0-9],\\{", "");
```

But really, REALLY, use a proper JSON parser!